# Can you predetermine the colour of a soundcloud oembed player in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, soundcloud, audio-player, oembed

How can I change the color of the soundcloud player (in wordpress) without having to include the hex colour code, in every instance that I embed a soundcloud iframe into a post in wordpress

For example - Instead of the :

```
<iframe src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/104054925&amp;color=ff3366&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false" width="100%" height="166" frameborder="no" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

I would like to just post a link like so:

https://soundcloud.com/banksbanksbanks/banks-waiting-game-prod-by

and somehow in the wordpress theme predetermine the colour of the player as being (#ff3366 for example)

Do I have the same flexibility to customise the player, as I would with a youtube embed. A youtube customisation being for example not displaying the title on videos with the code below.

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'my_embed_oembed_html', 99, 4);
function my_embed_oembed_html($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
return '<div class="entry-embed">' . $html . '</div>';
}

function iweb_modest_youtube_player( $html, $url, $args ) {
return str_replace( '?feature=oembed', '?
feature=oembed&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&rel=0&HD=1', $html );
}
add_filter( 'oembed_result', 'iweb_modest_youtube_player', 10, 3 );
add_filter('embed_handler_html', 'custom_youtube_settings');
add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'custom_youtube_settings');

?>
```

Comment: The soundcloud documentaion detail the funtionality you require [here]( https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/widget).

Comment: Im not much of a coder, could you give me an example of how I can achieve the desired effects please Jon C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example add the follwing to the bottom of functions.php

```
    //Add soundcloud as oembed provider
    wp_oembed_add_provider( 'http://soundcloud.com/*', 'http://soundcloud.com/oembed' );

    //function to adjust colors and options
    function soundcloud_theme_embed($html, $url, $attr) {
    //Change the color here and adjust the options based on //https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/oembed#introduction
    $url = $url.'?iframe=true&maxheight=150&show_comments=false&color=ff3366';
    //get the udated url so you only have to type https://soundcloud.com/banksbanksbanks/banks-waiting-game-prod-by into content
    $embed_code= wp_oembed_get($url);
    //turn off visuals so you can see the color change
    $newHtml=   str_replace( '?visual=true', '?visual=false', $embed_code );
    //replace output with newly created output
    $html=$newHtml;
    return $html;
    }
    //add your function to the fitler https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hookfilter-for-auto-embed-function-of-wp
    add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'soundcloud_theme_embed', 10, 4 ) ;
```

You could add an option for the color in the theme by following the documentation outlined [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API)

For example you would change this line so that the colour was a variable and read it from the theme, or you could adjust the code and create a plugin adding the options there

```
    $url = $url.'?iframe=true&maxheight=150&show_comments=false&color=ff3366';
```

would become

```
    $url = $url.'?iframe=true&maxheight=150&show_comments=false&color='.$themeColor;
```

Comment: Thank you Jon C you are a star !!

Comment: I am trying to change the height of the iframe but changing the "maxheight" variable is not having any effect. Can you offer any advice?

Comment: the max height is set in the code adjust it here     $url = $url.'?iframe=true&maxheight=250&show_comments=false&color

Comment: I already tried changing that variable, yet nothing has happened thhe iframe does not change in height. take a look http://www.milkin.it/editorial/sss/

Comment: Cant see if from your link and from my test page it works as expected changing those elements in funtions.php makes the output change height

Comment: I fixed it, by changing the css varibles in my theme

.entry-embed iframe, .entry-embed object, .entry-embed embed,

from height: 100% to height: auto. 

Thank you for your help

Comment: Is there a way to create a css class for the embed in the php ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. but if you mean can you add a class to to iframe you could adjust the example above. for instance i could find another element inside the iframe and replace the string  like this         $newHtml2=   str_replace( 'scrolling="no"', 'scrolling="no" class="customclass"', $html );
$html=$newHtml2;